# What do we have in common?

Tags: riddle, pattern, knowledge

In each category, all the animals have something in common, and all the categories are related.

---

## Category 1a:

Walruses, birds, ponies, tigers, elephants, cats, monkeys, bulldogs, bees, raccoons, cats,  octopuses, pigs, bullfrogs, blue jays, Eagles, worms,  fish, horses,  homing birds, blackbirds, kittens,  hogs, crabs, penguins,  doves,  sheep, sheepdogs, glow worms, butterflies, canaries, puppies, lizards, lambs.

## Category 1b:

Roosters, songbirds, cats, dogs, horses, sheep, lions, elephants, cows, hens, crickets, blackbirds, either ducks, swans, or geese.

---

## Category 2:

Rams, horses, alligators,  frogs, bison, bluebirds, blackbird, cocks, seagulls, cows, snakes, honeybees, inchworms, dragonflies, moose (meese?), geese, koala bears, magpies.

Struszia (trilobite)

## Category 3:

Chicken, fish, monkey.

Struszia (trilobite)

## Category 4:

Mouse, blackbird, monkey, reindeer.

Avalanchurus (trilobite)

## Category 5:

Turkey, hound dog.

Bumba (tarantula)

---

### What is the theme of each category?  What do all the categories have in common?  Provide an example of each item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

> Animal names related to the BEATLES.

**Category 1a:**
Walruses, birds, ponies, tigers, elephants, cats, monkeys, bulldogs, bees, raccoons, cats,  octopuses, pigs, bullfrogs, blue jays, Eagles, worms,  fish, horses,  homing birds, blackbirds, kittens,  hogs, crabs, penguins,  doves,  sheep, sheepdogs, glow worms, butterflies, canaries, puppies, lizards, lambs.

> **Animal names** occuring in songs by the Beatles: 
>  I am the walrus. Free as a Bird. And Your Bird Can Sing. Dig a Pony. 
>  Bungalow Bill went out tiger hunting with his elephant and gun.
>  Three Cool Cats. Everybody's Got Something To Hide Except Me And My Monkey.
>  Hey Bulldog. Bees. Rocky Raccoon. Octopus's Garden. Piggies. 
>  Hey Bulldog (Bullfrog, doing it again). Blue jay way. Etc. etc. etc.

**Category 1b:**
Rooster, songbirds, cat, dog, horse, sheep, lion, elephant, cow, hen, crickets, blackbirds, either ducks, swans, or geese.

> **Animal sounds** occuring in songs by the Beatles.
>  Good Morning Good Morning (starts with rooster crow, birds, a cat, 
>  a dog, a cow, a horse, a sheep, a lion, an elephant, and a 
>  group of bloodhounds).
>  Sun King (cricket sounds).

**Category 2:** 
Rams, horses, alligators, frog, bison, blue birds, blackbird, cock, seagull, cow, snake, honeybee, inchworm, dragonfly, moose, goose, koala bears, magpies.
Struszia (trilobite)

> **Paul McCartney:** Album "ram"; songs "All You Horse Riders", 
>  "Alligator", "Rupert and the Frog Song", "Bison", "Bluebird", 
>  "Blackbird", "Great Cock and Seagull Race", "Cow", "What It Is", 
>  "The inchworm", "Little Lamb Dragonfly", "Morse Moose & The Grey Goose",
>  "Ode To A Koala Bear", "Two Magpies".
>  Struszia mccartneyi (trilobite) named after him.

**Category 3:** Chicken, fish, monkey. Struszia (trilobite)

> **George Harrison:** Song "Tandoori Chicken", "Fish on the Sand", 
>  "Tweeter & The Monkey Man".
>  Struszia harrisoni named after him.

**Category 4:** Mouse, blackbird, monkey, reindeer. Avalanchurus (trilobite)

> **Ringo Starr:** Songs "Scouse The Mouse", "Bye Bye Blackbird", 
>  "Monkey See - Monkey Do", "Rudolph the Red-Nosed Reindeer". 
>  Avalanchurus starri named after him.

**Category 5:** Turkey, hound dog. Bumba (tarantula)

> **John Lennon:** Songs "Cold turkey" and "Hound dog". 
>  Tarantula "Bumba lennoni" named after him.

Comment: BING!  Nailed it.

Comment: @CapyStenchbeast You seem like a good girl.  This is a crazy coincidence - my dog's name is Capy Stenchbeast!  People are going to think that I set up a sock account so the answer wouldn't be obvious immediately;  and after the question was answered, I realized that I could accept it but not vote on it.,so I logged onto my main account.

Comment: @WadCheber  OHMYGOD!  I'M a dog myself!  Thanks for calling me a good girl, it makes me really happy, then my butt starts wiggling. The totally hypothetical situation you just mentioned is absurd and definitely not true.   This situation  is just too funny.  Well, goodbye forever, Puzzling.SE. I'm never coming back.

Comment: @CapyStenchbeast - Bye.  Stop chewing on my slippers.

Comment: Gamow - Your choice of words is different from mine, but the meaning is the same.  I thought of it as:  1a:  Animals mentioned in Beatles songs, 1b:  animals heard in Beatles songs, 2-5:  Animals mentioned in titles of songs by former Beatles, each with an animal named after the person in question.

Comment: Error:  *Hey Bulldog*, not "Bullfrog" (although bullfrogs are mentioned in that song).  Missing:  1a:  eagles, worms, sheepdogs, penguins, bees, homing birds, blue jays, kittens, canaries, lizards, puppies, lambs, sheep, crabs, hogs.  1b -  blackbirds, and "either ducks, swans, or geese." 2:  snakes.  I would appreciate correcting the error, but whether or not you add what is missing is up to you.

Comment: 1a:  Eagles and worms: Yer Blues.  Sheepdogs:  Hey Bulldog, Martha My Dear.  Penguins, crabs:  I Am The Walrus.  Hogs:  Come Together, Being For the Benefit of Mr. Kite.   Lizards:  Happiness Is A Warm Gun.   Blue Jays:  Blue Jay Way.  Unless I'm missing one, the rest are from songs *covered* by the Beatles, e.g., Kittens:  Leave My Kitten Alone.

Comment: 1b:  Blackbirds:  Blackbird, something else that I can't remember at the moment.  Either ducks, swans, or geese:  Across the Universe (WWF version).

Comment: Oops - another one from 1a:  Butterflies:  It's Only Love.

Comment: Again, don't feel obligated to add these.  I'm just mentioning them for the sake of trivia.